# Where to get / how to build a 50" / 1.25 m. long GPIO cable

Tags: gpio, cable

I want to connect my 433.92MHZ transmitter to my Pi.

The problem is, it's 50" away from my pi, and the only cables I can find online are 20 cm (8") long cables.

I've thought about creating the cable myself from a 230V electric cable, but then I also couldn't find the little connectors to put on the end.

And if I'm lucky, I would like the cable a three-in-one, because the transmitter needs 3 cables, and it would look better (because the transmitter is in my living room) if there is just one cable (like a three wire electricity cable, that is what I mean with three-in-one)

Hope this question in my limited English makes sense ;-)

Comment: what signals are you sending down the cable? If it's anything high-speed you will need not be able to drive a plain cable that long, and should look at either converting to a differential pair (and even then you have limits, e.g. USB is differential but limited to 3 metres ); if it's just on and off every few seconds then it will be Ok.

Comment: Those connectors are called dupont connectors. You could just rip them out of an old PC, and extend them using any 3-wire cable you can find in you local hardware store.

Comment: @pete I think it's high speed, I'm not sure. I'm using a library class for it (). But the length is not a problem i think, because it is already running at this cable length, but now I'm using 6 pieces of rainbow colored 20cm M/F cables connected together, and that doesn't look pretty.

Comment: @Gerben thanks for the name 'Dupont'. that got me started on google!

Comment: If you want, I can send you some. As we live in the same country, it's only a single stamp. It's slightly more difficult without a dupont-crimping tool, but doable.

Comment: Thanks for the offer Gerben, but I already went crazy on Ebay ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need 26way ribbon cable. You can find 26way ribbon cable in various lengths on Ebay. [1m](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/RIBBON-CABLE-26WAY-PER-M-28AWG-300V-191-2801-126-1207444-/350921910270?pt=UK_BOI_Electrical_Components_Supplies_ET&hash=item51b49367fe), [5m](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Spectra-Strip-Twisted-Pair-Ribbon-Cable-455-278-26-x-7-34-26-way-5mtrs-/390393712703?pt=UK_BOI_Electrical_Components_Supplies_ET&hash=item5ae547503f), [30m](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Flat-Grey-Ribbon-Cable-30m-Reels-for-IDC-Connectors-7-Sizes-Available-/130693394342?pt=UK_BOI_Electrical_Components_Supplies_ET&var=&hash=item1e6deeefa6).

That link for the 1m lengths looks like they sell by the meter, so if you order 2m then you'll get a 2m length, not two individual meter lengths. I'd recommend checking with them before you order though.

For hooking up the connectors, they're simple clip fits. [Instructions](http://reprap.org/wiki/MakeIDCCable) on connecting the connectors to the ribbon cable.

[image]